# Jenkins with Cleracase - Creating Automatic Baselines in CC and triggering Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am new to Jenkins and need some help.

We have ClearCase and Jenkins running on same machine (windows).

I am trying to configure Jenkins with clearcase through basic CC or CC UCM plugin. But i am not sure which one i need to choose.

My Current Process :
Step 1: Once developer deliver the code to Integration region in clearcase, Devops team manually do the baseline for Int stream and also do the rebase.
Step 2: And with some batch script they build the process and move the ear or jar to particular region.

Now i need to automate this process through Jenkins, where i got stuck with automating baseline and rebase in clearcase which they are doing it manually now. i think once the baseline creation is done by developer or through command process only Jenkins will be triggered to start the job.

So please suggest me the exact steps which i need to start automating the whole process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> basic CC or CC UCM plugin. But i am not sure which one i need to choose.

If your view is built from a Stream, you need UCM. If not (simple config spec with your custom rules), you need Base.
In your case, you will use the [Jenkins ClearCase UCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin)

All you need to do is test that a job is triggered on a new baseline (even if that job does at first only a simple `echo "It work!"`)

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/58001105/polling_smaller.png?version=2&modificationDate=1319721419000&api=v2]

> Like the Git and Mercurial plugins, ClearCase UCM Plugin also supports polling for the latest baseline. This means, when polling, a build is scheduled only if there's a new baseline on the stream.
>
> To be able to poll for the latest baseline, the special promotion level ANY and self polling must must be selected in the setup.

Once that is working, you can add in that job a Windows shell build step which will execute the very same command you would have typed manually in order to do the rebase ([cleartool rebase](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm)...).
If you can script it manually (outside Jenkins), you can add it to a Jenkins job trivially.

Comment: @Java_Sol Sure, but be sure to accept the answer only if you make it work, not before ;)

Comment: All you need to do is test that a job is triggered on a new baseline (even if that job does at first only a simple echo "It work!") by adding this "Poll Self" whether i need to do "Make Baseline" manually in clearcase or Jenkins is taking care of creating the baseline ?

Comment: No, that would be to detect baseline created by others

Comment: ..So Manual creation of "Make Baseline" is must for Jenkins to detect the latest code delivery.

Comment: if possible can you please provide me link or script from clearcase to create a automatic Trigger for "Make Baseline".

Comment: @Java_Sol a trigger is done after an operation, so you need first to know after which command you wish to make a baseline. Typically, in your case, you might want to create a baseline after a delivery: `ct mktrtype -ucmobject -all -postop deliver_complete -exec` as seen in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013869984. See mktrtype at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm

Comment: i am able to create a baseline through perl script and able to call the script from Jenkins. Now i am trying to add new job in Jenkins, but i am getting the below issue. can you please suggest me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Building in workspace C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test Forms
[CCUCM] ClearCase UCM Plugin version 1.7.0
[CCUCM] Allow for slave polling: false
[CCUCM] Poll for posted deliveries: false
[CCUCM] Trim changeset: false
[CCUCM] Polling streams: self
[CCUCM] Getting baselines for :
[CCUCM] * Stream: XXXXX_XXX_POC_Int@\pvob
[CCUCM] * Component: XXXX@\pvob
[CCUCM] * Promotion level: ANY

[CCUCM] Retrieved 4 baselines:
[CCUCM] + XXXXX_v2014.12.011(Tue Jul 18 11:45:32 PDT 2017)
[CCUCM] + XXXXX_v2014.12.012(Thu Jul 20 09:56:15 PDT 2017)
[CCUCM] + XXXXX_v2014.12.013(Thu Jul 20 10:39:13 PDT 2017)

Comment: [CCUCM] + XXXXX_v2014.12.014(Thu Jul 20 14:23:05 PDT 2017)

[CCUCM] Using XXXXX_v2014.12.014@\XXXXXX
[CCUCM] View root: C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test Forms\view
[CCUCM] View tag : CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736
[CCUCM] Determine if view tag exists
[CCUCM] Creating new view
Unable to create view CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736 at C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test Forms\view
Command was: cleartool mkview -snapshot -stgloc -auto -tag CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736 -stream stream:CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736@\pvob "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test Forms\view"

Comment: cleartool: Error: No available Server Storage Location entries.
Command: cleartool mkview -snapshot -stgloc -auto -tag CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736 -stream stream:CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736@\pvob "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test Forms\view"
Path: null
java.io.IOException:

Comment: @Java_Sol Can you make a new question? That will allow others to have a clearer view of the error message (properly formatted).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338034/clearcase-ucm-configuration-with-jenkins-to-get-latest-baseline-integration-code

Answer (score 0):

From a non-Jenkins standpoint, you may want to find out when the "Devops" folks create the baselines. It is possible (though not recommended) to create those baselines in a postop deliver_complete trigger. (Baseline and label accumulation can have long-term performance impacts and may not be easy to clean up...)

If they have set up a trigger to create the baseline, you might be able to skip the whole "polling" by adding whatever is needed to trip the rebase and build within the trigger.

Comment: Actually we don't have trigger setup as of now.Devops folks are doing baseline and rebase manually. i like to setup a trigger to create the baseline.

Comment: "Devops" team is creating the baselines manually in the Integration stream by incrementing baseline process and also doing the rebase by "Rebase to the recommended baselines" . So my question is whether i can automate both the process inside Jenkins or still i need to maintain the Making baseline manually.

Comment: @Java_Sol Baseline creation generally assumes some sort of vetting process has been done. If the build you are trying to trigger is the vetting process, you could automate baseline creation, but tread carefully. Excessive baseline counts can really drag the UCM GUI performance down, and deleting baselines is either annoying or  impossible, depending on your project structure.