# Clearcase UCM Configuration with Jenkins to get latest baseline Integration code

Tags: jenkins, configuration, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Can someone please help me why am I getting this error?

I am running Jenkins from one of my VDI machine and connected to Clearcase windows server. I am able to get the latest baselines so basically it is getting connected to clearcase server but I am not sure why it is changing the stream name while running the command.

Console Output:

```
Building in workspace C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test Forms
[CCUCM] ClearCase UCM Plugin version 1.7.0
[CCUCM] Allow for slave polling: false
[CCUCM] Poll for posted deliveries: false
[CCUCM] Trim changeset: false
[CCUCM] Polling streams: self
[CCUCM] Getting baselines for :
[CCUCM] * Stream: XXXXX_XXX_POC_Int@\pvob
[CCUCM] * Component: XXXX@\pvob
[CCUCM] * Promotion level: ANY

[CCUCM] Retrieved 4 baselines:
[CCUCM] + XXXXX_v2014.12.011(Tue Jul 18 11:45:32 PDT 2017)
[CCUCM] + XXXXX_v2014.12.012(Thu Jul 20 09:56:15 PDT 2017)
[CCUCM] + XXXXX_v2014.12.013(Thu Jul 20 10:39:13 PDT 2017)
[CCUCM] + XXXXX_v2014.12.014(Thu Jul 20 14:23:05 PDT 2017)

[CCUCM] Using XXXXX_v2014.12.014@\XXXXXX
[CCUCM] View root: C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test Forms\view
[CCUCM] View tag : CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736
[CCUCM] Determine if view tag exists
[CCUCM] Creating new view
Unable to create view CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736 at C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test Forms\view
Command was: cleartool mkview -snapshot -stgloc -auto -tag CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736 -stream stream:CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736@\pvob "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test Forms\view"
cleartool: Error: No available Server Storage Location entries.
Command: cleartool mkview -snapshot -stgloc -auto -tag CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736 -stream stream:CCUCM_Test_Forms_XXXX27005736@\pvob "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test Forms\view"
Path: null
java.io.IOException: 
at net.praqma.hudson.remoting.CheckoutTask.invoke(CheckoutTask.java:125)
```

Comment: Would this command work if executed manually? Under which account does this Jenkins run?

Comment: @VonC i am seeing the command is having wrong stream name and  -tag. i am not sure what you mean by account here, but Jenkins is able to pull the latest baseline from clearcase. so jekins is able to access the clearcase. If possible we will have one small skype or chat so that i can explain the exact issue which i am facing also about my environment. my email Id: anand.mathialagan3@gmail.com

Comment: @VonC I think the above command will work if i change the correct stream name and tag, also i need run the command under the UNC Path M:\$user\$UCMIntgView.

Comment: You should be able to configure your UCM Jenkins plugin to use a dynamic view instead of a snapshot one.

Comment: in that case i need to choose Base clearcase in source Code Management section instead of clearcase ucm right?.

Comment: Yes, but you will have to see if it detects the latest label in that case (non-UCM)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to build from a given baseline, my bet is that the Jenkins UCM integration created a build stream. This would be the most correct way to ensure that the build is not impacted by stream changes. (Not very likely in a *snapshot* view, but that's beside the point.)

The error message is likely because of missing "storage locations" You can predefine there you want the view/VOB databases to reside using `cleartool mkstgloc` and list them with `cleartool lsstgloc.`